# TransformClassesWithNewClassShrinker Failed

Tags: compiler-errors

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithNewClassShrinkerForStagingDebug'.

> /Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt line 43:15 extraneous input '[]' expecting ')'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set this:
   "minifyEnabled true"
,you should change to:
   "minifyEnabled false"
,and then everything will be ok!